# How to Remove Slaves that have been terminated but Sentinel still sees

Tags: redis, sentinel

When I check my slaves

```
redis-cli -p 26379 sentinel slaves mycluster
```

I get some ips that have already been nuked.

Is there away to take them out of sentinel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send `SENTINEL RESET master` command to every sentinel to remove these slaves.